# Arduino Zero (ATSAMD21G) - I2C - continuous wrong data flow

Tags: i2c, arduino-zero

I encountered a strange behavior while running 2 way transmission tests  between 2 Arduino Zero (ATSAMD21G), one master and one slave. Wrong data is being continuously transferred both ways. The expected data is also being transferred in between. I have to filter out the received data to catch it (line 41 in Master's code and 33 in slave).

I'm using the stock wire libraries (being different for the 2 boards), along with Nick Gammon's "I2C_readAnything".

[Master's code](https://github.com/kb-/Arduino-I2C-2way-anydata/blob/master/Master_test_i2c_data/Master_test_i2c_data.ino)

[Slave's code](https://github.com/kb-/Arduino-I2C-2way-anydata/blob/master/Slave_test_i2c_data/Slave_test_i2c_data.ino)

I think this continuous flow doesn't allow the bus to be released. It might be what's making it impossible to communicate with a second master (and maybe causing my [previous problem](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/34944/two-way-communication-on-multimaster-i2c-bus))

I also tried my code between a Mega 2560 (slave) and a Zero (master). Fake data is, this time, only being sent one way (from the Zero to the Mega only).

Is there some specific code to add to send data properly from ATSAMD boards? Is it a bug in the SAMD Wire library?

I also had to add a 1ms delay after sending data from the Master. It wouldn't go through otherwise. Shouldn't it be handled by the ATSAMD or the Wire library?

Answer (score 1):

The code had several issues.

`receiveEvent`, on the slave side, contained a `millis` `if` condition timer that made it time out. I moved the timer to the master side before calling `Wire.requestFrom`.

`receiveEvent`, on the slave side, was also confusing real data with incoming `requestEvent`. I added an `if` statement to compare the `receiveEvent` data size with the expected size. Half of the data was wrong without this filter (this should ideally be handled in the `Wire` library)

I set the global variables used in events as `volatile`. The code is working too without this tho.

[fixed Master code](https://github.com/kb-/Arduino-I2C-2way-anydata/blob/f781617142bd0198ea9d41a78125e3cb52f5399c/Master_test_i2c_data/Master_test_i2c_data.ino)

[fixed Slave code](https://github.com/kb-/Arduino-I2C-2way-anydata/blob/f781617142bd0198ea9d41a78125e3cb52f5399c/Slave_test_i2c_data/Slave_test_i2c_data.ino)

Comment: The Slave I2C clock is 100kHz, the Master has 800kHz. Start with the most normal settings, that means also the Master at 100kHz. The return values are not tested in the Master. I think in this situation you should test them. In the Slave you could test the howMany and increment an error counter if it is not right. The I2C bus is not fault tolerant, that means it should always work 100%. If it is unreliable, you should fix it. How long are the wires ? When you connect a 3.3V board via I2C to a 5V board, did you use a level shifter ? Did you connect the GND's of both boards ?

Comment: Do you mean the remaining wrong data I'm filtering out with by testing howMany shouldn't be there? When I test it like you advise, I see it's half of the receiveEvent (not a continuous flow anymore, so it's good enough, the bus gets released after each transaction so multimaster is working too now). That's why I think it's confusing requestEvent with data. I'll understand more once I get my logic analyzer.

Comment: The Master sets I2C bus speed. The slave's code doesn't contain speed setting. 800 kHz works fine between 48 MHz Nano but too much with the Mega. The wires are less than 1 m long. I'm using a level shifter between the Nano and the Mega. All on same GND. I'll add a test on the data content in my final application for extra safety.

Comment: I don't care if 800kHz worked in the past. You have to fix a number of problems, therefor returning to 100kHz would be wise. If everything works fine, you could try higher clocks speeds. But you are not there yet. The I2C communication should work 100%, not 99%. When the howMany is only half of the receiveEvent okay, then your I2C communication is working 50%. You have to fix the problems to make it 100%. Start by using the default I2C clock speed of 100kHz en test the return values in the Master. Maybe you could also store the howMany in a variable when it was wrong and print that variable.

Comment: Same @100kHz. howMany = 0 for half of the receiveEvent. For these, Wire.read returns -1, meaning no data.

Comment: Thanks for testing. That is very weird. Normally, only a collision in a Multi-Master bus could cause that. The howMany is the number of valid bytes waiting in a buffer. When you read more than the amount of valid bytes, the Wire.read returns -1. I'm out of ideas. It could still be a hardware problem, do you have pullup resistors ? My best guess is that it is a problem in the Wire library for the Zero. I can find a number of issues with the Wire library for Arduino Zero / Feather M0 / Arduino M0 (all ATSAMD21G).

Comment: I made some more tests. Pullups are there, around 2 kOhm. I made a first test with 10 transfers, without howMany. The data was randomly wrong in the serial print, but all good on the logic analyzer! [code and result](https://github.com/kb-/Arduino-I2C-2way-anydata/tree/cb5ea4863f77e6eb323db0bbd84c01d5734e1fd9) Then I made another test with 10000 transfers, with howMany. Any single transfer was good in both the serial print and the logic analyzer. [code and result](https://github.com/kb-/Arduino-I2C-2way-anydata/tree/b8525944b4ef0c0166e8c4d66c1b1bcf2adbd2cb). I'm confused about the 1st result!

Comment: It means to me that the Wire library is sometimes triggering receiveEvent when there isn't any incoming data. It's not a big issue tho since there's no wrong data or collision on the bus.

Comment: You need to test it at 100kHz. If you can do the same at 100kHz then I suggest to assume that it is a bug in the library and you should work around it. Perhaps the receiveEvent is sometimes accidently called when the I2C transaction has just started. When the Master requests data, the Master should send a NAK at the end, but it doesn't. I read that when writing a register in a Slave followed by reading that register, sometimes a short delay (1ms) is needed between the Wire.endTransmission and Wire.requestFrom. That means there are already three things to improve for the SAMD21 Wire library.

Comment: It's behaving the same at 100 kHz. I only see NACK at the end of the reads, before the stop with the logic analyzer. The howMany workaround made it possible to transmit with 100% success. Thanks for all your advises. Adding the other tests you suggested plus retry on collisions made it possible to use the code for multi-master 2 way transmission.

Answer (score 0):

Start with a single byte, with a very small sketch, with both the Master and the Slave at 100kHz. When that is working 100% reliable, then you can try to transfer a struct.

The Slave RequestEvent function should always return valid data, not once every two seconds. The global variables that are used in receiveEvent or requestEvent **and** in the loop() should be made 'volatile'. Disable the interrupts in the loop() when reading or writing the global volatile struct.

With your sketch, you have to open the serial monitor for both the Master and Slave.

You could add more tests, for example testing the return value of Wire.endTransmissing, testing the 'howMany' parameter, testing the actual number that Wire.request returns.

Comment: I simplified the code to test with a single byte 2 way transfer @100 kHz, using volatiles in events like you advised. I'm still seeing the same behavior (after opening monitor on both of course). Transferring one way only is working properly.
Adding more tests sounds to me that it would only hide that fake data is flowing between the devices (like the filtering I did in my initial code). I have to avoid disabling interrups because my final application relies on them (PID motor control and encoder reading...)

Comment: Result on slave:
"Arduino connected
...
ÿ
ÿ
m
ÿ
ÿ
ÿ
..."

(should get "m" only; same behavior on master side)

[Master](http://tinyurl.com/hm2nsfc)     /   
[Slave](http://tinyurl.com/zyder4a])     /    
[One way only Master](http://tinyurl.com/hq47p9v)

Comment: I figured out what didn't work in the simplified test. The millis delay in requestEvent was causing it to timeout. I put this delay before requestFrom in the master instead. I have to test the "howMany" parameter in the receiveEvent so it doesn't confuse incoming data with a requestEvent. This should be handled by the wire library in my opinion.  [Fixed code](https://github.com/kb-/Arduino-I2C-2way-anydata/commit/88d35b78301265cacf743e1f00232c59bbe0aadc)